# Timings in directive - no complete initial value

Tags: angular

I'm having problem with timings in my custom directive.
Here is a reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gufrps

This directive should add or remove text regarding attribute value. 
Changing of content is triggered with `@Input()  set myDir(v: boolean) {}` method.
Problem is that if init value is set to `true` it does not have `options` yet set so it throws error. How to fix that timing? Should I use `timeout`? I think it's a dirty solution and hope there is another.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes - sorry for not marking as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are adding the message by calling `add()` as soon as setting `myDir`, at that moment it's not having `myDirOptions` and so code is breaking. I have modified your code as:

**HTML**

```
<div 
    [myDir]="showHello"
    [myDirOptions] = "myDirOptions"
    style="width:200px; height:200px; background: yellow"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
myDirOptions={text:' Hello'};
```

**directive.ts**

```
private showMessage: any;

@Input()
set myDir(v: boolean) {
    console.log('Value set: ', v);
    this.showMessage = v;
    if (v) {
      this.add();
    } else {
      this.remove();
    }
}

@Input()
set myDirOptions(v: any) {
    this.options = v;
    if(this.showMessage != undefined) {
        this.showMessage ? this.add() : this.remove();
    }
}

add() {
    if(this.options) {
      console.log('options: ', this.options);
      this.el.innerHTML='Hello '+ this.options.text;
    }
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urctse)